# Что такое цоб и цобе?

Tags: этимология, лексика, значение-слов, социолингвистика

В одно тексте мне встретилась такая фраза:

> А здесь что услышишь? Лишь **«цоб»** да **«цобе»**?

Что значат выделенные слова? Каково их происхождение и где они употребляются?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

В этимологическом словаре М. Фасмера:
[**цобе́**](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/vasmer/50600/%D1%86%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B5) — "направо", цоб — "налево", южн., также в укр., согласно Потебне у Горяева (ЭС 404).

Вот что об этом пишет [**В. Н. Войнович**](http://www.famhist.ru/famhist/voinovich/002418c0.htm) ("Цоб-цобэ - искусство управления волами"):
..."цоб" и "цобэ" — это, во-первых, команды. Причем довольно простые. Если говоришь "цоб", волы поворачивают налево, "цобэ" — направо, "цоб-цобэ" — идут прямо. Во-вторых, Цоб и Цобэ — это не только команды, а еще имена. У всех волов есть только два имени: Цоб и Цобэ.
(...) Цоб в упряжке всегда стоит справа, а Цобэ, наоборот, слева. (...) Погонщик знает, что если надо повернуть налево, то следует стукнуть (несильно) стоящего справа Цоба и сказать ему: "Цоб!" Тогда Цоб напряжется и толкнет плечом стоящего от него слева Цобэ, тот подчинится, и волы повернут налево. А если направо, то Цобэ толкнет Цоба — и все получится наоборот. Точный, ясный, раз и навсегда заведенный порядок.

*но волы не аргамаки, цоб-цобе да цоб-цобе…

в ковылях краснеют маки, словно слезы по судьбе…

по судьбе, что хриплым скрипом

страсть души помалу выпьет,

примиряя с цоб-цобе…*
Геворк, "цоб-цобе"

*А здесь что услышишь? Лишь «цоб» да «цобе»?* — рутина, беспросветность, глухая деревня, тяжелый труд ("напрягая свои натертые шеи, мерно перебирая ногами, передними, просто грязными, и задними, обляпанными во много слоев навозом"), одно и то же изо дня в день.

Comment: Ну ничего ж себе! А я всегда считал, что это что-то вроде ономатопеи, типа щёлкнуть языком для лошади О_О.

Comment: Сразу вспомнился фильм "Кавказская пленница", больше нигде и не встречал  эти слова:  
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PCivWd3bRMg